# mount() fails because target container is not dom element

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm getting error message `Target container is not a DOM element`. Using webpack.

**Full Error:**

```
FAIL  src/App.test.js
 ● Test suite failed to run

Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

  at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
  at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17238:34)
  at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17317:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:32:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:5:14)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Tables from './containers/Tables/Tables'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Tables />
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import aaaApi from '@aaa/aaajs';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import tableBuilderReducer from './store/reducers/tableBuilder'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';    

const aaa = new aaaApi('xxx');

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const reducers = {
  platforms: tableBuilderReducer('platforms'),
  regions: tableBuilderReducer('regions'),
  playback: tableBuilderReducer('playback')}

export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(aaa)),
  ),
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import App from './App' 
import { store } from './index.js'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

function setup() {
    const props = {
        sortColumnHandler: jest.fn()
    }

    const enzymeWraper = mount(<App />)

    return {
        props,
        enzymeWraper
    }
}

describe('components', ()=> {
    describe('Tables', () => {
        it('should render self and sub-components', () => {
            const { enzymeWraper }  = setup()
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: can you show the code for App.js?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors added!

Comment: the issue is that somehow `index.js` is getting included when Jest goes to run `App.test.js`.  I don't see anything obvious from `App.test.js` or `App.js`.  Is `index.js` getting included in the Jest config files (setupFiles, etc.?)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors It's my first time writing test code and someone else set this up, so I'm not sure where I should look at, but the only thing I could find was `module.exports = {... appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/index.js'),...}`  in `config/paths.js` which I don't think should be a problem...?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I think I found it. I had `import { store } from './index.js'` in `App.test.js` which I didn't include in the post when I was cleaning up the code to post in here. But deleting that gives me another error, which is `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Component)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Component)"`

Comment: cool, I think I have enough info to give a proper answer.  Let me know if it covers what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being caused by `index.js` being included in the test and is failing at `ReactDOM.render()` when `root` is not found in the document created by the `jsdom` environment in Jest.

`import { store } from './index.js'` is not needed in `App.test.js` so removing that will fix the initial error.

Using `mount` from `enzyme` does a [full DOM rendering](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#full-rendering-api-mount) and requires that everything be set up for a full render.  It should only be used to unit test components that use lifecycle methods, interact with the DOM, etc.  It will fully render the component being tested and all children components.  In this case the children of `App` use the redux store so a store would need to be provided in a wrapping `Provider` in order to do a full render using `mount`.

In most cases, React components should be unit tested using `shallow`.  It does a [shallow rendering of just the component being tested](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallow-rendering-api).  In this case `App` is a simple stateless component that contains `Tables` so using `shallow` is the right approach.

**bonus tip:**

Install [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json#enzyme-to-json) as a dev dependency, add it to Jest as a snapshot serializer, and `App.test.js` gets simplified to this:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';

describe("App", () => {

  it('renders as expected', () => {
    const component = shallow(<App />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});
```

Comment: Great, that worked! One more thing, the `App` component does have a child component `Tables` that gets props using `connect` and makes an ajax call in `componentDidMount`. In this case, should I then test the `Tables` component separately using `mount`?

Comment: Yep, test it separately.  Yes, if a component has logic in `componentDidMount` then using `mount` is the only way to test it.  Sounds like you'll have to wrap `Tables` in a `Provider` to `mount` it.  (...and you'll want to mock the ajax call so your unit tests aren't causing network requests)